# laravel go to page pagination

Tags: php, html, pagination, laravel

Any idea how to go to a specific page of pagination?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I follow your question. Has David Barker answered it, or are you wondering how to load a specific page without the query string in the URL?

Comment: Please specify your question a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

All you would need to do is duplicate the links the paginator creates to go to the page you want.

```
echo HTML::link('controller?page=2', 'Link Name');
```

As long as the route or controller is setup properly this would generate page 2 of the paginator results for you on load.